# Find 2nd last record(if available otherwise the last record) in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with record like

[image]

Here I want the Id 4 and 7 and 9

In this I want the details of every 2nd (if it have many) record . In the above table I want to fetch Id 
(4 for ticketid 1001), 
(7 for ticketid 1002) and 
(9 for ticketid 1003) .
for ticketid 1003 it should fetch id 9 because it have no other id.

Comment: What version of sql server? Also show your sample data as text so that we can create a sql fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With sql-server 2005 and newer you could use this approach:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, Status, TicketID,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TicketID ORDER BY ID DESC),
           CNT = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TicketID)
    FROM dbo.TableName t
)
SELECT ID, Status, TicketID
FROM CTE
WHERE CNT = 1 OR RN = 2
```

If you don't want to use a common-table-expression which is similar to a subquery/view:

```
SELECT x.ID, x.Status, x.TicketID
FROM ( SELECT ID, Status, TicketID,
              RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TicketID ORDER BY ID DESC),
              CNT = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TicketID)
       FROM dbo.TableName t ) x
WHERE x.CNT = 1 OR x.RN = 2
```

Comment: can we do it without using **CTE** ? just like simple select .   Actually I want to join this result with huge data so it will be great if we find some alternative. btw thanks for you answer.

Comment: @Subo: You can join this CTE with other tables. It's just the same as if you use a simple subquery.

Comment: @Subo: However, i have edited my answer to provide a subquery.

Comment: Awesome buddy . Let me check .Thanks @Tim

Answer (score 0):

Try with this following,

generate a sequence number for your table and then in apply a condition in where clause.

i.e. where derived column name %2 = 0

and please share your full information means what is your data and what you exactly want from that input.

so we will give get some more clarity on your problem and will provide the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this more a comment than an answer? Also, he has provided data and a desired result.